# Can and should I use JDK 9 for development of Java 7 / Java 8 software?

Tags: java, java-9

The target environments of my code use older Java versions (Java 7, Java 8). I use JDK 7 for development.

Will there be advantages if I use the most up-to-date JDK for my development, which is JDK 9 (and specify source=1.7 and target=1.7)?

I am aware that my code must not use any API which is not availabke on the target platform.

Comment: If you use JDK 7 for development, you cannot specify Java 8 as a target. Now, AFAIK you can specify Java 7 as binary source if you use JDK 9... **But**, I do not see the reason for doing that - personally, I would install proper JDK (and IDE) for producing the required code... BTW, you couldn't exploit the advantages of JDK 9  in tje Java 7 source...

Comment: @zlakad this is why I wrote that I must set source and target to 1.7 if I switch my JDK and use JDK 9

Comment: You have absolutely no reason to use JDK 9. Personally I treat it as beta software until it will appear as 'recommended' in https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Comment: @Oleg interesting point, thank you for the link

Comment: @Oleg, this is not *beta* software - Oracle is way ahead of developers (IDE developers, 3rd party libraries, you name it). JDK 9 is **stable** product, and it will be accepted to eliminate *maven* and similar so-called dependencies.

Comment: If you like trying something quickly, jdk9 ships with jshell tool, maybe that is advantage of having jdk9 installed at least.

Comment: @zlakad so you are saying JDK 9 will remove the need for build tools? Do you have any source for that?

Comment: I agree with @mjn, but there is **always** *but*... If you use jshell, and try something like `List lst = List.of(..` you cannot apply that in the previous versions of Java.

Comment: @Kayaman, that would be a purpose for 'Jigsaw' - module development.

Comment: @zlakad no, I was talking about build tools, modules are but a tiny part of them. You seem to have a very superficial understanding on what JDK 9 brings (Jigsaw, JShell) and you talk like you understand more than you really do. Please don't do that, it will only confuse people who think you are speaking from experience.

Comment: @Kayaman, I think the building tools will stand for some time - maybe, I didn't understood the modules, but If I do, modules 'explains' what are the dependencies they *depends* of.

Comment: @zlakad It's impossible to know if something new is stable or not, there are almost always problems early adopters discover and need to deal with. For now Oracle themselves don't trust Java 9 which is a good indication that it's not known to be stable yet.

Comment: @Oleg *Oracle don't trust Java 9*? It might be, but I didn't read anything about that. I'm so sorry, maybe I am not well informed. No hard feelings, friends - It seems to me that I believe in Java 9 more than Oracle? Huh... If it's true, I urge Oracle to fix it. ;)

Comment: @mjn A very basic question, why don't you give it a try and come back? What's stopping you? I don't think SO could be equivalent to a discussion forum for such questions anyway. Plus there are now a lot of articles to read over the comparison, I would suggest you go through [Nicolai's blogs](https://blog.codefx.org/tag/java-9/) to see a lot more around Java-9.

Answer (score 5):

For the *can I?* Yes. Since backwards compatibility is important in Java, there's no technical reason why you couldn't do it. Sometimes company policies mandate a specific JDK version for development though.

In general the main advantage of using a later version of the JDK than what you're developing for is getting familiar with the later version. This may also increase your interest to migrate the software itself to a later version, if you notice it to be useful: for example you notice you love lambdas, so you migrate from Java 7 to Java 8.

Since the resulting bytecode is the same (not that it really matters) and the tools you use usually don't depend on the JDK, it has very little other effect. You can (usually) run code safely on newer JREs, so there's no difference with that either.

---

For the *should I?*

Whether you should start using JDK 9 now is primarily a matter of opinion. As Oleg pointed out it's not actively pushed everywhere, so at least you're not late and have time to consider moving forward for a while still (maybe toy around with it first before considering it for work use). Due to the large architectural differences between Java 8 and Java 9, I'd expect there to be a lot bigger gap in acceptance than between older versions.

However it's not all gloomy. There's a pretty good wrap-up of the features [here](https://blog.takipi.com/jdk-9-checklist-project-jigsaw-sun-misc-unsafe-g1-repl-and-more/) and even if you are sticking to Java 7/8 projects for the time being, I see no reason not to do that on JDK 9 when you feel you're ready to have a look at it (and there is no hurry). I haven't installed it yet, although I've read about the decisions (good choice they didn't remove `Unsafe`).

Comment: May I ask, why didn't you installed JDK 9? Do you think it would harm you in any way? BTW, I'm not a professional, I'm just a hobby programmer, so I *really* want to know **why**...

Comment: I'm not much of an early adopter and JDK 9 doesn't have anything I'm dying to try, so I don't go out of my way just for that.

Comment: It's O.K with me.